# Deciphering a scoring equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've recently had to take an intelligence assessment test and I was curious about how the scoring could've been done. So I'm posting here to see if anyone has any good guesses.

Test & Scoring description description:

The person is asked to complete as many tasks as possible within a 2 minute time frame. All the tasks are similar.

Score ranges from 0 - 100.
The more answers you answer within a 2 minute limit the higher your score.
The more accurately you answer your questions within a 2 minute limit the higher you score. 
The scores are displayed as integers.

I'm aware that there probably isn't just one correct answer but I'd like to see the sort of equations people think would fit this scoring system.

Comment: There is really a very wide range of such functions. Hoiwever, if the scores are additionally required to be integers, we can infer that there are at most 50 questions.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for the comment! Could you give me an example of such a function ?